# find and delete whole line in txt file

Tags: c#, linq

if I have txt file with content separated by tabulator like this

```
 00013  ITEM1   20.00   2   1   01  0.000   2   0.000   0.00    0.000   0.00    
 00014  ITEM2   20.00   1   1   01  0.000   2   0.000   0.00    0.000   0.00
```

Since `00013` represents `item.Code` and this is unique value I want to pass this `item.Code` as parameter and find and delete whole line.

After delete operation file content would be

```
00014   ITEM2   20.00   1   1   01  0.000   2   0.000   0.00    0.000   0.00
```

Once more, how can I find and delete whole line in txt file? Should I use linq? How would you do it.

Thanks

Comment: you can use view or store procedure for that..

Comment: this is not db content, at least I do not have access to db.

Comment: then how your table will be generate

Comment: can you use .edmx file on that

Comment: which table :) This is file with generated content, doesn't matter how.

Comment: OOP's srry... k i understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
void FilterFile(string fileName, string newFileName, string itemCode) 
{
    var mathcedLines = File.ReadLines(fileName).Where(l => !l.StartsWith(itemCode));
    File.WriteAllLines(newFileName, mathcedLines);
}
```

Comment: This will not meet OP's requirements.  OP is looking to *remove* the matched line, not keep it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use LINQ.

```
var result = from line in File.ReadAllLines(path)
             where !line.StartsWith("00013")
             select line; 
File.WriteAllLines(path + "new", result);
```

That would cover the file operation. Now as for the rest of your question, I'll admit I don't 100% understand what you are asking.

Other options to consider for your file operation include loading the lines into a `List`, then using `FindIndex()` then `RemoveAt()`. This method only removes one item, which is fine, given your constraint on the data that the value we're looking for is unique.

Comment: You could shorten it to `var result = from line in File.ReadAllLines(path)...` as well.

Comment: You have a typo in last line must be `result` instead `list`.